# Passing values from a fragment to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-fragmentactivity

I have a DialogFragment which has a listView as container. I've set up OnItemClickListener on the listView.

How can I get the value when the user touchs an item and pass it to another activity then  store that value into a variable? I need to set a count down timer depending on which  item will be selected. Actually can only display simple toast message with the item position.

As a note, the activity to which the value will be passed is not the fragment activity.

I was thinking about Bundle but have not having much knowledge on programming is a pain even after reading documentation on Google site.

on the MainActivy, here is how I set the timer:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String elapsedTime = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            timer.setText(elapsedTime);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText(R.string.text);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Exemple:

If user touches item 1 then the timer gets value 15 minutes and so on...

Please guide me, thank you.

Comment: The best idea is to use the Interface concept than a bundle. @Lyra

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to pass data from Fragment to Activity. Here is how you do it.

**Passing the data from Fragment to Activity:**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityName.class);
intent.putExtra("counter-value", counterValue);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

**Reading the value in the Activity:**

```
final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    final int counterValue = extras.getInt("counter-value", -1);
    showCountDown(counterValue);
}
```

Now, Pass the value to the `countdowntimer`.

```
private void showCountDown(final int counterValue) {
    new CountDownTimer(counterValue, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String elapsedTime = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            timer.setText(elapsedTime);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText(R.string.text);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So where do I have to call the Bundle?

Comment: inside the `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Oh... I don't get you. I mean reading the value passed to the MainActivity. As shown on my code, I need to store that value into a variable the use that variable to set the timer

Comment: @Lyra, in `onCreate()` check whether `getIntent() != null` and take a bundle.

Comment: Hi @CoolMind, do you mean reading the value by "take a bundle" ? Sorry for being so ignorant and dumb

Comment: You have 30k (millisInFuture) replace that with the value received through the bundle in MainActivity.

Comment: @Lyra, yes, like Srikar wrote.

Comment: Oh, okay start to understanding... BUT counterValue cannot be resolved. I put the code with Bundle on onItemClickListener of the listView then on the MainActivity, I place the code to the timer by changing millisInFuture with counterValue

Comment: I'm lost on whether  to create that value then initialize it?

Comment: Move the counter to a method and pass the counterValue to it or make counterValue a global variable